# API REST JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

I want to use the API jquery.rest on [this site](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139)(for example), I execute anything on my console.
here is my script

```
 var client = new $ RESTClient ('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139');
 client.show ();
```

nothing appears on my console

Comment: What is `RESTClient` a class you wrote or a library?

Comment: That API don't support CORS so you can fetch it using just javascript, you need to create server side proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi why dont you try using the the jQuery's built in `$.ajax()` call using `jsonp` dataType? [see here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

here is my successfull attempt:

```
var URI = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139';
$.ajax({url:URI,dataType:"jsonp"})
      .done(function(object){
        //now you can access your object like any other json object e.g.
        alert(object.sys.country);
      })
      .fail(function(){
        alert("oh no - something went wrong!");
      });
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this : https://github.com/jpillora/jquery.rest then it looks like you have the capitalization wrong.

try:

```
var client = new $.RestClient('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139');
client.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

milkshake's response is what you are after. - just to suit your need , I am converting your json object into string - so you can have better idea.

```
  var URI = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139';
    $.ajax({url:URI,dataType:"jsonp"})
        .done(function(object){
          //now you can access your object like any other json object e.g.
         alert(JSON.stringify(object));
      })
      .fail(function(){
        alert("oh no - something went wrong!");
      });
```